# Почему не записывает текст в файл? c#

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Есть код (c#) -

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          if (File.Exists("C:\\gam\\config.dfg"))
          else 
          {
          Console.WriteLine("Файл не существует");
                File.Create("C:\\gam\\config.dfg");
                File.WriteAllText("C:\\gam\\config.dfg", "самый простой способ", Encoding.Default);
                Console.ReadKey(); 
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Файл действительно создается, однако ничего внутрь него не пишется, и вылезает  ошибка, подчеркивается строка "file.WriteAlltext" и пишется "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "C:\gam\config.dfg", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно, что после выполнения предложения  File.Create("C:\\gam\\config.dfg"); созданный файл открывается. А вызов File.WriteAllText требует, чтобы файл был закрыт. Так что после первого вызова вам следует закрыть файл.;

Comment: К тому же, в данном случае вообще можно обойтись без File.Create, WriteAllText создаст файл, если тот отсутствует.

Comment: `File.Create` возвращает `FileStream`, который держит файл, пока не будет закрыт. Вам эта строка вообще не нужна. `File.Create("C:\\gam\\config.dfg").Close();`

Comment: Просто уберите `File.Create`.

Answer (score 4):

В комментариях к методу `Create` записано (автоматический перевод корявый, но вполне читаемый:)):

> FileStream Объект, созданный с помощью данного метода по умолчанию
>   FileShare значение None; другой процесс или код может получить доступ
>   к созданного файла пока не закрыт исходный дескриптор файла.

Так что либо вы продолжаете работать с этим файлом, используя возвращаемое значение объекта типа `FileStream`, либо закрываете его после вызова этого метода.

Что касается метода `WriteAllText`, то

> Создает новый файл, записывает в него указанную строку и затем
>   закрывает файл. Если целевой файл уже существует, он будет
>   переопределен

Поэтому вы могли бы воспользоваться только этим методом, не вызывая метод `Create`.